# What is elegant way to create array from list?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have this string:

```
"(Id=7) OR (Id=6) OR (Id=8)"
```

from the string above how can I create array or list like this:

```
"Id=6"
"Id=7"
"Id=8"
```

Comment: Have you _ever_ try to capture between `(` and `)` characters with regex for example and put them in a `string[]`?

Comment: [`\(([^)]*)\)`](https://regex101.com/r/eM1dB0/1) with Global flag, and access captured group 1

Comment: It seems reasonably to ask how you want to treat any AND? Or maybe it's not possible to have any other separators than OR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using Regex but with some Linq you could write

```
string test = "(Id=7) OR (Id=6) OR (Id=8)";
var result = test
    .Split(new string[] { " OR "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Select(x => x = x.Trim('(', ')'))
    .ToList();
```

If you need also to take in consideration the presence of the AND operator or a variable number of spaces between the AND/OR and the conditions then you could change the code to this one

```
string test = "(Id=7) OR (Id=6) OR (Id=8)";
var result = test
    .Split(new string[] { "OR", "AND"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Select(x => x = x.Trim('(', ')', ' '))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: What if there is more than 1 space between `)` and `OR`?

Comment: Remove the spaces around the OR and add a space char to Trim

Comment: Yes, but I feel there may be more *if*s that are usually easier to adjust using a regex.

Comment: Perhaps you are right, but if this is a WHERE condition then it is possible that there are no braces around the ID=X and, in this case the Regex solution should be different. (And in any case if there is an AND instead of OR also my answer becomes irrelevant). But now we are bordering the problems of an SQL Parser and this is probably not the real problem in the question.

Comment: I also believe that it is a good idea to avoid regex whenever possible

Answer (score 3):

I suggest combining regex and LINQ powers:

```
var result = Regex.Matches(input, @"\(([^()]+)\)")
       .Cast<Match>()
       .Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value)
       .ToList();
```

The `\(([^()]+)\)` pattern ([see its demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C((%5B%5E()%5D%2B)%5C)&i=(Id%3D7)%20OR%20(Id%3D6)%20OR%20(Id%3D8))) will match all `(...)` strings and use the Group 1 (inside unescaped `(...)`) to build the final list.

Answer (score 1):

Simply grab the matches

```
(?<=\()[^)]*(?=\))
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iJ7bT6/18

```
string strRegex = @"(?<=\()[^)]*(?=\))";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.Multiline);
string strTargetString = @"(Id=7) OR (Id=6) OR (Id=8)";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
   if (myMatch.Success)
   {
     // Add your code here
  }
}
```

Comment: Two points: 1) the lookarounds are not necessary since you can use groups, 2) the snippet does not yield a list as the result.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew making list should be a trivial task

Comment: Yes, and I showed how it can be done in my answer. There is another LINQ way with `OfType`, BTW.